# Regular Expression to get A-Z, excluding other characters and numbers

Tags: plsql

I have a field `Facility` with some of the following records:

```
ABC-XY
ABC-ZZ
EFG-AA
NM
NM-100
NM-202
HYK-109
LI-022
```

How can I get the letters before the hyphen, but also get the letters when no hyphen is present (like in `NM`) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex should be:

^ [A-Z]+

^ is the start of the string, allowed character class  A-Z can present more than once until some other character is found.

Comment: or `\w+`, it is more shorter :-)

Comment: @Egor : thanks for the tip. I'm not so familiar with shortcuts available in plsql, just wanted to answer as OP stated the problem.